# ModelChoiceField in forms.Form won't validate if queryset is overridden

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I have a django ModelChoiceField that won't validate if I override the queryset.

```
class PersonalNote(forms.Form):
    tile    = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tile.objects.none())
    note    = forms.CharField()

form = PersonalNote()
form.fields['tile'].queryset = Tile.objects.filter(section__xxx=yyy)
```

The `form.is_valid()` error is: "*Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices*".
If `Tile.objects.none()` is replaced with `Tile.objects.all()` it validates, but loads far too much data from the database. I've also tried:

```
class PersonalNote(forms.Form):
    tile    = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tile.objects.none())
    note    = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        yyy = kwargs.pop('yyy', None)
        super(PersonalNote, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if yyy:
            self.fields['tile'].queryset = Tile.objects.filter(section__xxx=yyy)
```

What might be wrong here?  Note the real application also overrides the label, but that does not seem to be a factor here:

```
class ModelChoiceField2(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        assert isinstance(obj,Tile)
        return obj.child_title()
```

Answer (score 3):

After 2 hours I found the solution. Because you specified a queryset of none in the class definition, when you instantiate that PersonalNote(request.POST) to be validated it is referenceing a null query set

```
class PersonalNote(forms.Form):
    tile    = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tile.objects.none())
    note    = forms.CharField()
```

To fix this, when you create your form based on a POST request be sure to overwrite your queryset AGAIN before you check is_valid()

```
def some_view_def(request):
    form = PersonalNote(request.POST)
    **form.fields['tile'].queryset = Tile.objects.filter(section__xxx=yyy)**

    if form.is_valid():
         #Do whatever it is
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an empty queryset to `ModelChoiceField` you're saying that nothing will be valid for that field. Perhaps you could filter the queryset so there aren't too many options.

Comment: Right.  How do I filter the queryset?  Neither approach above worked.

Comment: In the modelform, the same way you pass it an empty queryset (`Tile.objects.none()`). You could narrow down the valid choices with a `filter()`.

Comment: In order to filter I need access to the yyy parameter, that's the sticky point.  Numerous examples show using none() in the constructor, then adding the queryset later.  It works, except for validation.

Comment: Ah, I see. A possible solution could be to override the appropriate field clean method, ie: `clean_tile()`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. The idea is to dynamically change the queryset of a `ModelChoiceField` based on a condition (in my case it was a filter made by another `ModelChoiceField`).

So, having the next model as example:

```
class FilterModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class FooModel(models.Model):
    filter_field = models.ForeignKey(FilterModel)
    name = models.CharField()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo_field = models.ForeignKey(FooModel)
```

As you can see, `MyModel` has a foreign key with `FooModel`, but not with `FilterModel`. So, in order to filter the `FooModel` options, I added a new `ModelChoiceField` on my form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = MyModel

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # your code here
       self.fields['my_filter_field'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(FilterModel, initial=my_filter_field_selected)
       self.fields['my_filter_field'].queryset = FilterModel.objects.all()
```

Then, on your Front-End you can use Ajax to load the options of `foo_field`, based on the selected value of `my_filter_field`. At this point everyting should be working. But, when the form is loaded, it will bring all the posible options from `FooModel`. To avoid this, you need to dynamically change the queryset of `foo_field`.

On my form view, I passed a new argument to `MyForm`:

```
id_filter_field = request.POST.get('my_filter_field', None)
form = MyForm(data=request.POST, id_filter_field=id_filter_field)
```

Now, you can use that argument on `MyForm` to change the queryset:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # your code here
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id_filter_field = kwargs.pop('id_filter_field', None)
        # your code here
        if self.id_filter_field:
            self.fields['foo_field'].queryset = FooModel.objects.filter(filter_field_id=self.id_filter_field)
        else:
            self.fields['foo_field'].queryset = FooModel.objects.none()
```